# JavaScript: why code didn't work on click function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want to use the click() function to return the attributes and value of forms in HTML and then add them into a string. 
Here is my code.  For "form", I just want to get those value one time while the "input" label can be retrieved multiple times:

```
var target="http://www.aaa.com/";
var clicktime=0;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").click(function(){
    var c=this.method;
    var d=this.action;
    var e=d.substr(17)
    $("#test2").text("the method is:   " +c+"   "+"The action part is:"+ "    "+e);
    if (clicktime=0){
    target=target+e+"?";
    }
    clicktime=1;
    $("#test1").text("you choose the following links:"+ "    "+target);
    });
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    $("input").click(function(){
    var a=this.name;
    var b=this.value;
    target=target+a+"="+b+"&";
    $("#test1").text("you choose the following links:"+ "    "+target);
    });
});
```

The result should be like this after I click on form part in my browser:

```
the method is get The action part is /dec/DEC

you choose the following links: http://www.aaa.com/
```

While the result for I clicking on form part in my browser is that:

```
the method is get The action part is /dec/DEC

you choose the following links: http://www.aaa.com/dec/DEC
```

**"target=target+e+"?"; didn't work! Why? Similar function works well on "input" function!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
if (clicktime=0)
```

should be

```
if (clicktime==0)
```

`=`is an assignment operator.
`==` is a comparison operator.

Comment: @AlienArrays Not if you're using only numbers. For strings, yes.